# Targeting ONLY my image sprite via CSS

Tags: css, css-sprites

OK, sorry...this is kind of a basic CSS question but it's driving me crazy. I'm self-taught so I'm sure I am just missing something simple.

Site: http://notes.benadelt.com

The logo image sprite is just a home link...I'm trying to remove that background color that you can see is ruining the transparency of the image:

```
<a class="ben-logo" href="/"></a>
```

You can see that CSS gives any links in that section a light background-color, which is being applied to the image sprite as well. I'm trying to remove that background color from my image, but not from the body links, and cannot figure it out. Using dev tools I can only impact the style using:

```
header .words a { background: none; }
```

But that obviously removes the background from ALL links, so it also removes my image background in the sprite.

Figured there would be something I could add after the background URL to do this, such as:

```
background: url(http://www.benadelt.com/notes/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Ben-Logo-Sprite.svg) none;
```

When you hover, it looks like I want it to look normally without that darn background-color.

Any help would be appreciated!

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header .words a.ben-logo { background-color: transparent; }`

The above code will target only the logo link. By setting the background colour to transparent, you leave the image itself (and all the other background properties!) intact.

Edit: One thing - I believe you already have transparent set on that background image by virtue of not specifying a colour (transparent is the default). What is probably happening in your case is that the `a.ben-logo` declaration comes before the `.words a` declaration in your stylesheet, so it's being overridden. The reason the above code should fix it is because the extra class names add more specificity. Here is Andy Clarke's specificity cheat sheet for you to peruse: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg

Comment: Beautiful! Added your more specific code to the very top of my custom styles and it worked. And you're right...my stylesheet is probably unorganized and that's causing problems. Clean-up time!